# log действий пользователя в git-shell

Tags: linux, git, ssh, логирование

Есть сервер `git`, все пользователи подключаются по `ssh`, в качестве оболочки используется `git-shell`.

Есть ли возможность записи в `log` всех команд переданных на сервер от пользователей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gitolite` использовать пока не хочется.

Почитал интересную статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/186732/

Включил `ForceCommand hook` в настройках `sshd`

Сам скрипт `hook`:

```
#!/bin/sh
    if [ ! -z "${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}" ]; then
            printf "%s - %s ip:%s. Runs a command: %s\n" $(date +%H:%M:%S) "${USER}" $(echo ${SSH_CLIENT} | awk '{print $1}') "${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}" >> /var/log/ssh/${USER}-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
            git-shell -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
    else
        cat /etc/motd
            ${SHELL}
    fi
```

Поместил его в `/usr/sbin` и символьную ссылку в `git-shell-commands` каждого пользователя.

Может у кого есть ещё предложения?

Answer (score 0):

Бегло взглянув на [исходники git-shell](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/shell.c), вижу, что средств логирования, вроде бы, не предусмотрено.

т.е., нужен некий *wrapper*.

В качестве которого можно использовать, например, `/usr/bin/script` (см. `man script`).

---

В качестве альтернативного варианта предлагаю использовать пакет *gitolite*, присутствующий, насколько я знаю, во всех популярных дистрибутивах. Там есть логирование (обычно даже включенное по умолчанию).